# How to assign a new value to the table inside Compile?

Tags: performance-tuning, syntax, compile

Consider some tables and function `func`:

```
phivals=RandomReal[{-Pi,Pi},10^5];
func[phi_]=phi^5*Exp[-phi];
acc=Table[0,10^5];
```

I would like to assign the new value to the ith element of `acc` depending on some condition on ith element of `phivals`. This is my code:

```
accnew = Hold@Compile[{{phivals, _Real, 1}}, Module[{val}, Do[
       val = func[Compile`GetElement[phivals, i]];
       acc[[i]] = Boole[0.1 < val < 1], {i, 1, Length[phivals], 1}]], 
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
   DownValues@func // ReleaseHold
```

The code is very slow:

```
accnew[phivals]//AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.84727,Null}

It is probably related to the fact that `acc` is not among the arguments of the compiled function. However, I cannot add it:

> Compile::argset: The assignment to acc is illegal; it is not valid to
> assign a value to an argument.

Could you please tell me how to avoid this issue and speedup the code?

Comment: It's really annoying, but `CompiledFunctions` don't allow to pass arguments by reference; hence one cannot efficiently modify an existing array. On has to pass in by value, make a copy and then modify the copy. Otherwise, you will have calls to `MainEvaluate` in the code shown by ``CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[accnew]``. This indicates a communication overhead that typically defeats the purpose of compileing with `Compile`.

Comment: So in order to enable true call by reference, one has to set up a LibraryLink function. That's typically quite verbose and one has to write plain C code for that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is a toy example, but here's a way:

```
accnew2 = Hold@Compile[{{phivals, _Real, 1}}, Module[{val},
       Table[val = func[Compile`GetElement[phivals, i]];
        Boole[0.1 < val < 1], {i, 1, Length[phivals], 1}]], 
      CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
    DownValues@func // ReleaseHold;

foo = Table[0, 10^5];

foo = accnew2[phivals]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.001453, Null}  *)

foo == acc
(*  True  *)
```

Alternatively:

```
murf = (1 - UnitStep[0.1 - #]) (1 - UnitStep[# - 1.]) &@
    func[phivals]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.000474, Null}  *)

murf == acc
(*  True  *)
```